# Simplify the difference quotient

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Simplify the difference quotient $$\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}, $$ by rationalizing the numerator, where  $f(x) = \dfrac{-3}{\sqrt{x}} $.

Please help, I am stuck. The textbook says the answer is: $$\frac{3}{x\sqrt{a}+a\sqrt{x}} $$

My work so far: $$\left(\frac{-3}{\sqrt{x}} + \frac{3}{\sqrt{a}}\right) \, \frac{1}{x-a} $$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from your work:
$$(\frac{-3}{\sqrt{x}} + \frac{3}{\sqrt{a}}) \cdot \frac{1}{x-a}\\
=\frac{-3\sqrt{a}+3\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x}\cdot\sqrt{a}}\cdot\frac{1}{x-a}\\
=\frac{3(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{a})}{\sqrt{x}\cdot\sqrt{a}}\cdot\frac{1}{(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{a})(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{a})}\\
=\frac{3}{\sqrt{x}\cdot\sqrt{a}\cdot(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{a})}\\
=\frac{3}{x\sqrt{a}+a\sqrt{x}}$$

Answer (score 2):

hint: $\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{a} = \frac{x-a}{\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{a}}$

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align}\large\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}
&=\frac{\frac{-3}{\sqrt x}-\frac{-3}{\sqrt a}}{x-a}\\
&=-3\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt x}-\frac{1}{\sqrt a}\right)\times \frac{1}{x-a}\\
&=-3\left(\frac{\sqrt a-\sqrt x}{\sqrt x \sqrt a}\right)\times \frac{1}{x-a}\\
&=\color{orangered}-3\left(\frac{\color{orangered}{\sqrt a-\sqrt x}}{\sqrt x \sqrt a}\right)\times \frac{1}{(\color{orangered}{\sqrt x-\sqrt a})(\sqrt x+\sqrt a)}\\
&=3\times \frac{1}{\sqrt x \sqrt a} \times \frac{1}{(\sqrt x+\sqrt a)}\\
&=\frac{3}{x\sqrt a+a\sqrt x}\end{align}$$

Answer (score 2):

The key is to see the denominator as a difference of squares: $x-a=(\sqrt x)^2-(\sqrt a)^2$.
$$\frac{-\frac3{\sqrt x}+\frac3{\sqrt a}}{x-a}=\frac{3\frac{\color{blue}{\sqrt x-\sqrt a}}{\sqrt x \sqrt a}}{(\color{blue}{\sqrt x-\sqrt a})(\sqrt x+\sqrt a)}=\frac3{\sqrt x\sqrt a(\sqrt x+\sqrt a)}.$$